# how to persist a OneToOne variable for a given entity in JPA

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, jpa, one-to-one

I have two entities: Student and Address

I added an OneTeOne annotation in the Student class and in JSP page, I can get an address for a given student using ${stud.address.country} in a foreach JSTL tag.

It's working but the problem is: I have to persist a new Student through the phpMyAdmin and not via the JSP page.

So what I should add in the JSP code and in the the servlet code to add/persist a new student with its own data address data?

(am new a newbe in Java web)

[Here is the link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9ckn11jrsck5w2k/CRUDWebApplication%20-%207%20March%202013.zip) to the netbeans source project

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, phpMyAdmin is nothing else but a PHP based administration utility for MySQL. So, the simple answer you don't have to and shouldn't persist your entity with it when you're working in a Java environment.

Look into declaring a persistence unit for your project if you don't already have one. Based on your environment also find out how to set up a datasource connected to your MySQL instance, then use the [EntityManager API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html) to do your persistence operations.

I'd suggest starting with a tutorial on [JPA](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbpz.html) first. Specifically the part on [persistence units](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqw.html#bnbrj) and [application managed versus container managed entity managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqw.html#bnbqy).

Sorry, I don't think there is an easier way to point you in the right direction and I doubt there is a shorter route.

**Update**

I looked through your dropbox content and you seem to have mostly IDE generated code which should be fine and functional. Your persistence unit declaration is likely where your problem is.

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="CRUDWebApplicationPU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/studentDB2</jta-data-source>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties/>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The line `<jta-data-source>jdbc/studentDB2</jta-data-source>` - is `jdbc/studentDB2` a valid JNDI name for a java.sql.Datasource in your deployment environment? Basically, you have to configure a datasource in your deployment environment connected to your database (note that the configuration there is environment specific). Then you code should work just fine. For a better answer you'll have to be more specific.